# Why is SD2 not saved in emscripten's include path?

Tags: visual-studio-code, sdl, webassembly, emscripten

I'm just wondering why SDL1 is saved under standard emscripten path `\emsdk-master\upstream\emscripten\system\include` but SDL2 during first compilation with `USE_SDL=2` under 
`\user\.emscripten_ports\sdl2\SDL2-version_20\include`? This also leads to an faulty includepath `#include <SDL2/SDL.h>` in Visual Studio Code for Intellisense.